# is there any way I can run Linux commands in the web?

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation

I am looking for software/application that can help me of checking some Linux commands working in a browser irrespective of OS. I mean Live CLI in the browser.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm actually going to reopen this because the "master" question is asking almost exclusively about browser based ssh clients and it seems most of the answers center around that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amongst many other solutions for an online Linux emulator there is [Bellard's Javascript emulator](http://bellard.org/jslinux/):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have tested that in a XP  os PC and it's not working.  To be more specific about the Issue I can't type anything there. That's the Issue in XP

Comment: The shot was done from a Windows 7 machine. XP is rather deprecated anyway. Updated image with my `uname -a` command to proof it's working. It may be an issue with your Java on XP ;)

Comment: It's just Javascript so as long as you're running a modern browser, it shouldn't matter what platform you're on. I just tested it in Firefox 25 and Chrome 31 on XP and it worked fine.

Comment: OK I think its java - Xp issue. any way which one is better to use ? mine or yours ? for testing worked fine but for certainty which one I can use ?

Comment: @rajagenupula - honest answer: I'd use none of them ;)

Answer (score 1):

Ok have found something after some googling , http://www.compileonline.com/execute_ksh_online.php

Posting here for helping others:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just refer this link below tells you about the basic steps !!
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/executing-linuxunix-commands-from-web-page-part-i.html

Comment: Please paste part of the answer.

Comment: I think you got the answer from the first one looks great than this method just stick on with that! :)

Comment: No problem just post what is the important part. because every one not going to like the same answer & having different choices will be good.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.